# Under extrusion? Only after a pause at layer height!

Tags: creality-ender-3, underextrusion

The issue appears on my Creality Ender 3 Pro only after the pause, but it seems to correct itself after a while. From what I know, it seems most likely under extrusion. I've tried purges, still same issue. I only need this feature to drop nuts in a print. The part separates at exactly where I paused. It also looks **exactly** the same each time on the inside, with there being gaps between the layers (looks like under extrusion essentially).

So far I have managed to try:

- writing a custom purge line (like the one at the beginning of all prints) - the purge line looks beautiful on the bed but then on the print it still under extrudes.
- Pushing 50 mm of filament after a reheat, but before it restarts. - It still under extrudes
- Slowing the print to as low as 50 % speed when restarting

Bonus points I tried these things too when I thought it could be bad adhesion on restart:

- Turn the part cooling fans off for 1 layer before and 2 layers after
- Increase temperature of hotend by up to 15 °C (in increments of 5)
- Restarted the print immediately

The part separates here each time.
[image: The part separates here each time.]

But the print seems mostly fine before the pause.
[image: But the print seems mostly fine before the pause.]

Then after its just not looking to great for a while.
[image: Then after its just not looking to great for a while.]